# Want to create a sampling animation with gganimate

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I wish to create an animation showing the effect of sample size on sample mean and standard error. I got hold of this code.
But, R encounters a fatal error when running this code

https://aiexplorations.in/2015/09/05/animated-mean-and-sample-size/

```
library(animation)
#setting GIF options
ani.options(interval = 0.12, ani.width = 480, ani.height = 320)

#package containing saveGIF function
library(animation)

#setting GIF options
ani.options(interval = 0.12, ani.width = 480, ani.height = 320)
mu = 10.0
sd = 1.0
#a function to help us call GIF plots easily 
plo <- function(samplesize, iter = 100){
  
  for (i in seq(1,iter)){
    
    #Generating a sample from the normal distribution
    x <- rnorm(samplesize,mean=mu,sd=sd)
    
    #Histogram of samples as they're generated
    hist(x, main = paste("N = ",samplesize,", xbar = ",round(mean(x), digits = 2),
                         ", s = ",round(sd(x),digits = 2)), xlim = c(5,15), 
         ylim = c(0,floor(samplesize/3)), breaks = seq(4,16,0.5), col = rgb(0.1,0.9,0.1,0.2), 
         border = "grey", xlab = "x (Gaussian sample)")
    
    #Adding the estimate of the mean line to the histogram
    abline(v = mean(x), col = "red", lw = 2 )
  }
}

#Setting the parameters for the distribution


for (i in c(10,50,100,500,1000,10000)){
  saveGIF({plo(i,mu,sd)},movie.name = paste("N=",i,", mu=",mu,", sd=",sd,".gif"))
}
```

But I dont know how to do it with 'gganimate'.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with this as a start. It begins with making a DF in 2 for-loops with 3 sample sizes of 10, 50 and 100. `i` is the number of repetitions. `mean` and `sd` are taken from your code.

In the ggplot-part the DF is grouped for `n` and `i` and the mean for these groups is calculated - this will create later the vertical line for the mean.

The `gganimate` part of this is the last line `transition_states(i, state_length =.2)` which defines `i` as the state which should be changed in the animation. The `ggplot`- object is then animated with `animate(...)` in which definitions for the number of frames `nframes` and the numbers of frames per second `fps` is made together with some definitions for plot size.

```
df <- data.frame(i = as.numeric(),
                  x = as.numeric(),
                  sd = as.numeric(),
                  mu = as.numeric(), 
                  n = as.numeric())

mu <- 10
sd <- 1
df <- rbind(df, data.frame(i =i, x = x,n = n,
                           sd = sd, mu = mu))  

for (n in c(10, 50, 100)){
   for (i in seq(1,100)){
     #Generating a sample from the normal distribution
     x <- rnorm(n,mu,sd)
     i <- i
     # i <- rep(i, 10)
     df <- rbind(df, data.frame(i =i, x = x,n = n,
                                sd = sd, mu = mu))  
   }
}

p <- df |> 
   group_by(n, i) |> 
   mutate(m = mean(x)) |>
   mutate(n = as.factor(case_when(
     n == "10" ~ "sample size = 10", 
     n == "50" ~ "sample size = 50", 
     n == "100" ~ "sample size = 100"
   ))) |> 
   mutate(n = fct_relevel(n, "sample size = 100", after = Inf)) |> 
   ungroup() |> 
   ggplot() +
     geom_histogram(aes(x, fill = n), 
                    color = 'white', binwidth = .5) +
     geom_vline(aes(xintercept = m, color ='red')) +
     theme_bw() +
     theme(legend.position = 'none') +
     facet_wrap(~n, nrow=1) +
     geom_text(aes(x = 12, y = 30, label = paste('Iter = ',i)), alpha = 0.2,
              col = "gray", size = 5) +
     geom_text(aes(x = 12, y = 28, label = paste('Mean = ', round(m, 2))), alpha = 0.2,
               col = "gray", size = 5) +
    transition_states(i, state_length =.2)

animate(p, fps = 1, nframes=100, height = 10, width = 20, units = "cm", res = 150)
```

[image]